# Spring: How to inject values to fields annotated by custom annotation

Tags: java, spring

my custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface KmsProperty {
    String key() default "";
}
```

bean:

```
public class Prop {
    @KmsProperty(key = ApiKeyConstant.SERVICE_SECRET)
    private String serviceSecret;
}
```

I want to inject values to all fields annotated by `@KmsProperty`, these values come from different sources(property files, or third-party key management services), how can I do that on application startup?

Comment: Why not simply use `@Value`? Why do you need a specialized custom annotation?

Comment: @M.Deinum  Because its value comes from different sources depending on the currenct environment. For example, in local env, its value comes from application-local.yaml, but in prd env, I need to call a third-party api to get and set its value.

Comment: Still nothing that you cannot achieve with `@Value`. Register a custom `PropertySource` (not the annotation th actual implementation) which does that. This is the same way as Spring Cloud Config works (obtaining information from git, hasicorp vault etc, by registering specific `PropertySource` instances). I suggest to use that instead of trying to bolt on your own other solution.